# Delete file/folder even if a user is browsing folder.

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, delete-file

I have an install script where I from time to time need to delete files and folders. However, my problem is that some users might be browsing this folder, or file. This will throw the error "Directory is not empty". Is there a method or way that will just ignore users browsing ? Like a brute force delete?

Doing this in PowersShell or Cmd is what I would like.

E.g. `cmd /c rmdir "folder"`

The Remove-Item gives the same error. I need to be able to delete no matter what.

(Windows Server 2008R2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should not delete a directory if another a user is managing its contents. Technically, it requires the uninstaller to force all file/directory handles to be closed. That can cause unexpected side effects, so it is not recommended at all.

That being said, you can use `handle.exe` from the Sysinterals Suite to force close open file handles. Rolling up a custom action based on `handle` isn't that complicated.

I'd still advise you to avoid force delete. Instead, instruct the users to close any open files.

Comment: It has crossed my mind. Usually I agree on your statement regarding force delete. Thanks for input.